# Add image to a product attributes

Tags: php, product-attribute, html

i use this code to assign a image to a drop product attribute named `stock_status` (a dropdown att):

```
<?php $_stockStatus = $_product->getAttributeText('stock_status'); ?><img src="/media/atticons/<?php echo $_stockStatus; ?>.png">
```

every thing is allright .but in product pages which are not connected to this attribute or do not have any value of this attribute, a broken image with this location address will shown: `mysite.com/media/atticons/.png`.
how to remove this image from product pages which are not connected to `stock_status` attribute?

Comment: if($_product->getAttributeText('stock_status')):
 //do something
endif;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy option:

```
<?php 
    if($_product->getAttributeText('stock_status')):
        //do something
    endif;
?>
```

**EDIT:**

```
<?php if($_stockStatus = $_product->getAttributeText('stock_status')): ?>
    <img src="/media/atticons/<?php echo $_stockStatus ?>.png">
<?php endif; ?>
```

**MORE**

Above will not work if you have space in the attribute, so you could do this:

```
<?php if($_stockStatus = $_product->getAttributeText('stock_status')): ?>
        <?php 
          $_stockStatus = $_product->getAttributeText('stock_status'); // get value .
          $_stockStatus = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]+/", "-", $_stockStatus); // replace space with _ .
          $_stockStatus  = strtolower($_stockStatus ); // change to lower cases .
        ?>
       <img src="/media/atticons/<?php echo $_stockStatus ?>.png">
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: im new in magento. can you apply my code in yours pleas?

Comment: I did please see the answer again

Comment: your second code won't work. but first one works like a charm!

Comment: why it didn't work, what was the error? glade to help anyway

Comment: no error just won't show any thing in frontend. i should mention that my image name is not in english.